# Как определить частоту выполнения reordering'a?

Tags: java, jvm, memory-management

Есть следующий код:

```
class Shared {
   int x;
   int y;

   void increment() {
      x++;
      y++;
   }

   void check() {
      if (x < y) {
         System.out.println("Ooops! x < y");
      }
   }
}
```

И вот, я создаю два потока - один читатель, другой писатель.

```
Shared shared = new Shared();

Thread writer = new Thread(() -> {
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       shared.increment();
   }
});

Thread reader = new Thread(() -> {
   for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
       shared.check();
   }
});

writer.start();
reader.start();
```

Как можно понять, операции внутри **increment()** могут быть переставлены местами, чтобы JIT мог оптимизировать время выполнения программы.

И вот тут уже начинаются весёлые вещи. Запуская этот код на своей машине (MackBook Pro mid 2019), я столкнулся с такой зависимостью:

1) Если N < 1000 - вероятность того что операции `x++` и `y++` будут переставлены практически равна нулю.

2) Если N > 1000 - вероятность того что операции `x++` и `y++` будут переставлены уже начинает приближаться к 100%.

Как можно объяснить эту статистику?

Comment: Многопоточный код недетрменирован. Если вы и найдёте какую-то закономерность, то верна она будет только для вашего кода, выполняющегося на данной версии JVM и на вашей машине.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да, всё верно, но как мне лучше определить эту статистику? Какие инструменты использовать для анализа, в этом тоже был вопрос.

Comment: Боюсь, что для C1 и C2 диагностировать реордеринг в процессе jit-компиляции можно только просмотром ассемблерного выхлопа, другие инструменты вряд ли существуют. У Graal есть возможность посмотреть граф для execution и data flow, но сомневаюсь в его полезности. Реордеринг процессором так и вовсе чёрный ящик.